# Error obtaining UI hierarchy when using UI Automator Viewer

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I am trying to use UI Automator Viewer and have been testing on a device with Android version 10 and on another device with Android 9. I'm following the tutorial [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing).

When I try and run UI Automator Viewer then click the button in the top left I get this error:

> Error obtaining UI hierarchy
>
> Reason:
> Unexpected error while obtaining UI hierarchy

Details:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

In the command window I notice the following log:

```
11:39:38 E/Screenshot: Unsupported protocol: 2
```

In Android studio I have Android SDK Build-Tools version 30.0.2 installed.

I've tried restarting the viewer and still same issue. Also I'm not using Appium.

Comment: This might be because you have instances of Android Studio running. Just try to have UI Automator Viewer open only.

Comment: Still got the same error after closing Android Studio. At the moment I've kinda given up and am using Appium Desktop. I think it has similar functionality.

Comment: Hi @JoshuaAugustinus. i see the same error. Did you manage to resolve this or you continue to use Appium Desktop?